# How to use base Anaconda environment in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

My python program runs when I go to the terminal and type

```
activate base
python data_load.py
```

This is where python is located:

```
where python
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

Then I try to use PyCharm with Anaconda and I go to Settings > Project Interpreter > Add Local > Conda Environment > Existing Environment and C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe as the interpreter. When I click the run button data_load.py does not run properly and there is a runtime error saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anonymous/PycharmProjects/pytorchHelloWorld/data_load.py", 
line 4, in <module>
import pandas as pd
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", 
line 42, in <module>
from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", 
line 10, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 66, in <module>
from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 43, in <module>
from pandas.core.internals import BlockManager
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 76, in <module>
from pandas.core.sparse.array import _maybe_to_sparse, SparseArray
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sparse\array.py", line 33, in <module>
import pandas._libs.sparse as splib
  File "pandas\_libs\sparse.pyx", line 17, in init pandas._libs.sparse
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a custom `numpy` package/module in your project which collides with the library. If this is the case - try to rename the custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a PyCharm Enviornment.

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Comment: I thought I already created an environment as I said in my question. Or is that not a PyCharm Environment as you described?

Comment: You might be using a PyCharm Anaconda Enviornment. This allows you to make a virtualenv enviornment with all the anaconda packages.